# Javascript Intellisense for LOCAL variables in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

Is there a way in Visual Studio 2010 to activate Intellisense for LOCAL variables in Javascript files?

There is a [MSDN How-To](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514138.aspx) which explains, how to provide Intellisense for function parameters with XML comments. This works very well. But it doesn't work for local variables:
E.g:

```
// Intellisense for myObject works
function MyFunc(myObject) {  
    /// <param name="myObject " type="MyClass"></param>
} 

// Intellisense for myObject doesn't work
function MyFunc() {  
    /// <param name="myObject " type="MyClass"></param>
    var myObject = service.GetValue();
} 

// Intellisense for myObject doesn't work
function MyFunc() {  
    var myObject = service.GetValue();
    /// <param name="myObject " type="MyClass"></param>
}
```

Comment: can you show us the definition of `service.GetValue()` ?

Answer (score 2):

VS is awesome for C/C++/C#, but it's just mediocre for JavaScript. :) Use a "real" IDE like WebStorm, or Titanium Studio.

Comment: PhpStorm/WebStorm is the best tool out there for auto completion, +1 even if it doesn't answer the question, I don't think the OP wants to buy a new IDE

Answer (score 2):

In your second and third examples MyObject is a class variable of MyFunc, not a parameter of a function. The parameter notation are for function parameters only, so your notation is wrong to begin with.

The following example will provide fully functional IntelliSense for the Internal function MyFunc with parameter MyObject:

```
  var MyClass = MyClass || {};

  (function() {
     "use strict";

     MyClass.MyFunct = function(attrObj) {
        /// <summary>Get object from my service</summary>
        /// <param name="AttrObj">My attribute object</param>
        /// <returns type="MyObject">My return object</returns>

        return MyService.GetValue(attrObj);
     };

  })();
```